# changing port number but email still sent with older port in link

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I changed the port from 8069 to 8070 using these

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069
```

and then also in `config.py` I changed the port to 8070. 
It works with one exception. All the emails like password resets etc are still sending my users the port 8069. Where is the setting to change the email sending address so it portray the correct port number?

I am using odoo.

thanks

Comment: Did you check your Settings -> Technical -> Parameters -> System Parameters for parameter called 'web.base.url'?

Comment: On apache2 I had to create a new odoo virtual server with `ProxyPass / http://example.com:8069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8069/` in  `<VirtualHost *:80>` to change my port number successfully.

Comment: I didnt have to do that, fortunately it worked after a complete reboot of machine.